# Custom NPM package - Custom command line command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I recently created an NPM package called Project_1 (which I installed in another of my Node.js projects called Project_2) using the command:

```
 npm install --save ./path/to/Project_1
```

(Is there a better method to install a local package inside one other locally?)

So the packaje.json of Project_2 is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Project_2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Project_1": "file:../Project_1",
  }
}
```

In the npm package I created (Project_1), the JSON package is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Project_1",
  "scripts": {
    "custom-serve": "http-server ./website --port 8888 -o"
  }
}
```

When I am in the root of Project_1 I can launch from the terminal:

```
npm run custom-serve
```

And in this way I can execute my custom command.

I need to know **how to call** `npm run custom-serve` **inside Project_2** (also from the command line) after installing the Project_1 package as an npm dependency in Project_2.
So, in the root of Project_2 I would like to be able to run `npm run custom-serve` so that the command written in the Project_1 library is triggered.

How can I do this? How should I set the JSON packages? Is there a best practice for doing this? Do I need to add special scripts in .js?
This is because I have noticed that always when installing npm packages they provide commands that can be launched from the root of the project in which they are installed.

**NB**: The command `custom-serve` is just an example. I would like to create some custom commands inside the Project_1 and i want to be able to call them inside the Project_2 after the npm install of the Project_1 package.
I have already tried to create a script inside the Project_2 like so:

```
"scripts": {
      "custom-command": "cd ./node_modules/Project_1 && npm run custom-serve",
}
```

But it doesn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to answer your question if there's a better way to install a local dependency, there is via [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link).

Assuming the name in Project 1's package file is `project-1`, you can link it in Project 2 as follows (obviously using the paths that correspond to your setup):

```
cd ~/projects/project-1
npm link
cd ~/projects/project-2
npm link project-1
```

Secondly, if you want your package to expose a runnable command, you should configure this [in the bin section of its package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#bin). The path should point to an executable file, so to reuse the npm script, you could use `execute` as follows

**custom-command.js**

```js
const {exec} = require('child_process');
exec('npm run custom-serve');
```

And then add the bin section to the package.json of Project 1:

```json
"bin": {
  "custom-command": "./custom-command.js",
}
```

Comment: Thanks @thomaux for the tip of the linking.
Assuming the usage of the `bin` section of the package.json i must create a cli-application in order to expose runnable commands?
Or, for example, can i simply do in the Project_1 package:
`"bin" : { "my-program-command" : "npm run custom-serve" }`? And then after the install in the Project_2 inside the root i can simply run `my-program-command`?

Comment: @AndreC23 I haven't tried setting it up via a npm command yet as you describe, but from the docs unsure if this would work. So I assume what would work in your case is a JS file that either imports `http-server` and then runs it with the desired parameters or use exec to execute npm from that file. I'll update my answer to show the latter

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index file inside your Project_1, and you had Project1 as a dependency for Project2, you can just call the file and it will run the default start command:

In Project_1 package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Project_1",
  "scripts": {
      "custom-serve": "http-server ./website --port 8888 -o",
      "start": "npm run custom-serve"
  }
}
```

In Project_2 package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Project_2",
  "scripts": {
    "custom-command": "node Project_1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So can i, for example, create a command inside the Project_2 like:
`"custom-command": "node Project_1 && npm run custom-serve"`
is that what did you mean? Or i have to mandatory create the `start` command inside the Project_1 that calls the `custom-serve` command? And what if i have multiple commands and i have to choose which one to run?

And what if i don't have an index.js inside the Project_1? Maybe because Project_1 has custom commands that wrap other commands?